# how to solve multi upload with sftp in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, sftp

i'm having trouble using PHP Codeigniter to SFTP upload files to a remote server.
when i upload file more than one. so here my code:

```
for($row = 0; $row < $total; $row++)  
{
  $origin = $directory.$file[$row];
  $destination = $des.$file[$row];
  $send= $this->upload($config,$origin,$destination);   
  $filename = $file[$row];
  print_r($filename."\n");

} $this->sftp->close();
```

so if i have 1000 files to upload,and success upload from 1 until 50. but when file 51 fails to upload and get error message

> ftp unable to upload

what causes can display the error above,how to create handle to reconnecting and reupload next file. so this function:

```
public function upload($config,$origin,$destination)
{

    $connect = $this->sftp->connect($config);
    $upload = $this->sftp->upload($origin, $destination, 'ascii', '0775');
    //create handling upload
    return $upload;
}
```

and sample function upload from library sftp:

```
$file_to_send = @file_get_contents($locpath);
$sftp = intVal($this->sftp);
$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}{$rempath}", 'w');       
if (@fwrite($stream, $file_to_send) === FALSE)
{
  if ($this->debug == TRUE)
  {
    $this->_error('ftp_unable_to_upload');
  }
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE
```

source sftp library from [library sftp](https://github.com/chillyorange/codeigniter-sftp-library/blob/master/Sftp.php)

so how to handle to reconnecting and reupload file when upload get message ftp unable to upload. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to increase the page loading time If you are working on localhost.
once hosted no need of increasing the loading time.